# mod_rewrite if not a certain page

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a .htaccess file with the typical wordpress mod_rewrite:

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /blog/
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
 </IfModule>

 # END WordPress
```

However I need to allow a certain page to not get redirected.  that being 'domain/ee'
I tried adding:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}      -f
RewriteRule ^ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}    [L]
```

to the top.  As I read it, that should have checked to see if the page existed and if so not run the reset of the rewrite.  However it's not working.
any ideas? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the first rewrite rule something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(path/to/page)$ $1 [L]
```

These two rules should prevent rewriting any actual files or directories:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Comment: Great. thanks. 
I'll try this as well, but I got what I needed by adding a simple 301 to the top.
     redirect 301 /ee http://www.domain.com/ee/